# Apache arrow error during example code compilation

Tags: apache-arrow

After installing the apache arrow library on my computer, I tried running the c++ code example in the website (https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/cpp/examples/arrow/row-wise-conversion-example.cc) but consistently kept getting the same error. I though it was because of the compiler couldnot find the arrow directory but after putting the library in the same folder as the test, it still didnt run and kept giving the same error.

```
 g++ test.cpp
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `VectorToColumnarTable(std::vector<data_row, std::allocator<data_row> > const&, std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table>*)':
test.cpp:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `arrow::default_memory_pool()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x49b): undefined reference to `arrow::ArrayBuilder::Finish(std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array>*)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x555): undefined reference to `arrow::ArrayBuilder::Finish(std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array>*)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x60f): undefined reference to `arrow::ArrayBuilder::Finish(std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array>*)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x6b6): undefined reference to `arrow::int64()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x70b): undefined reference to `arrow::field(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::shared_ptr<arrow::DataType> const&, bool, std::shared_ptr<arrow::KeyValueMetadata const> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x72e): undefined reference to `arrow::float64()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x783): undefined reference to `arrow::field(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::shared_ptr<arrow::DataType> const&, bool, std::shared_ptr<arrow::KeyValueMetadata const> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x7a6): undefined reference to `arrow::float64()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x7bf): undefined reference to `arrow::list(std::shared_ptr<arrow::DataType> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x814): undefined reference to `arrow::field(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::shared_ptr<arrow::DataType> const&, bool, std::shared_ptr<arrow::KeyValueMetadata const> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0xa1a): undefined reference to `arrow::Table::Make(std::shared_ptr<arrow::Schema> const&, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array> > > const&, long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `ColumnarTableToVector(std::shared_ptr<arrow::Table> const&, std::vector<data_row, std::allocator<data_row> >*)':
test.cpp:(.text+0xef0): undefined reference to `arrow::int64()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0xf45): undefined reference to `arrow::field(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::shared_ptr<arrow::DataType> const&, bool, std::shared_ptr<arrow::KeyValueMetadata const> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0xf68): undefined reference to `arrow::float64()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0xfbd): undefined reference to `arrow::field(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::shared_ptr<arrow::DataType> const&, bool, std::shared_ptr<arrow::KeyValueMetadata const> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0xfe0): undefined reference to `arrow::float64()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0xff9): undefined reference to `arrow::list(std::shared_ptr<arrow::DataType> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x1048): undefined reference to `arrow::field(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::shared_ptr<arrow::DataType> const&, bool, std::shared_ptr<arrow::KeyValueMetadata const> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x11eb): undefined reference to `arrow::Schema::Equals(arrow::Schema const&, bool) const'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::detail::Fingerprintable::Fingerprintable()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow6detail15FingerprintableC2Ev[_ZN5arrow6detail15FingerprintableC5Ev]+0xf): undefined reference to `vtable for arrow::detail::Fingerprintable'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::DataType::DataType(arrow::Type::type)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow8DataTypeC2ENS_4Type4typeE[_ZN5arrow8DataTypeC5ENS_4Type4typeE]+0x45): undefined reference to `vtable for arrow::DataType'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::NestedType::~NestedType()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow10NestedTypeD2Ev[_ZN5arrow10NestedTypeD5Ev]+0x26): undefined reference to `arrow::DataType::~DataType()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::ListType::ListType(std::shared_ptr<arrow::Field> const&)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow8ListTypeC2ERKSt10shared_ptrINS_5FieldEE[_ZN5arrow8ListTypeC5ERKSt10shared_ptrINS_5FieldEE]+0x3c): undefined reference to `vtable for arrow::ListType'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::Buffer::ZeroPadding()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow6Buffer11ZeroPaddingEv[_ZN5arrow6Buffer11ZeroPaddingEv]+0x18): undefined reference to `arrow::Buffer::CheckMutable() const'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::Buffer::mutable_data()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow6Buffer12mutable_dataEv[_ZN5arrow6Buffer12mutable_dataEv]+0x18): undefined reference to `arrow::Buffer::CheckMutable() const'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::TypeTraits<arrow::Int64Type>::type_singleton()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow10TypeTraitsINS_9Int64TypeEE14type_singletonEv[_ZN5arrow10TypeTraitsINS_9Int64TypeEE14type_singletonEv]+0x27): undefined reference to `arrow::int64()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::TypeTraits<arrow::DoubleType>::type_singleton()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow10TypeTraitsINS_10DoubleTypeEE14type_singletonEv[_ZN5arrow10TypeTraitsINS_10DoubleTypeEE14type_singletonEv]+0x27): undefined reference to `arrow::float64()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::BufferBuilder::Resize(long, bool)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow13BufferBuilder6ResizeElb[_ZN5arrow13BufferBuilder6ResizeElb]+0x76): undefined reference to `arrow::AllocateResizableBuffer(arrow::MemoryPool*, long, std::shared_ptr<arrow::ResizableBuffer>*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::BufferBuilder::Finish(std::shared_ptr<arrow::Buffer>*, bool)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow13BufferBuilder6FinishEPSt10shared_ptrINS_6BufferEEb[_ZN5arrow13BufferBuilder6FinishEPSt10shared_ptrINS_6BufferEEb]+0x121): undefined reference to `arrow::AllocateBuffer(arrow::MemoryPool*, long, std::shared_ptr<arrow::Buffer>*)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::ArrayBuilder::ArrayBuilder(arrow::MemoryPool*)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow12ArrayBuilderC2EPNS_10MemoryPoolE[_ZN5arrow12ArrayBuilderC5EPNS_10MemoryPoolE]+0x17): undefined reference to `vtable for arrow::ArrayBuilder'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::ArrayBuilder::UnsafeAppendToBitmap(unsigned char const*, long)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow12ArrayBuilder20UnsafeAppendToBitmapEPKhl[_ZN5arrow12ArrayBuilder20UnsafeAppendToBitmapEPKhl]+0x2e): undefined reference to `arrow::ArrayBuilder::UnsafeSetNotNull(long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::ArrayBuilder::UnsafeAppendToBitmap(long, bool)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow12ArrayBuilder20UnsafeAppendToBitmapElb[_ZN5arrow12ArrayBuilder20UnsafeAppendToBitmapElb]+0x2e): undefined reference to `arrow::ArrayBuilder::UnsafeSetNotNull(long)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow12ArrayBuilder20UnsafeAppendToBitmapElb[_ZN5arrow12ArrayBuilder20UnsafeAppendToBitmapElb]+0x43): undefined reference to `arrow::ArrayBuilder::UnsafeSetNull(long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::ArrayBuilder::~ArrayBuilder()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow12ArrayBuilderD2Ev[_ZN5arrow12ArrayBuilderD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for arrow::ArrayBuilder'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::NumericBuilder<arrow::Int64Type>::NumericBuilder<arrow::Int64Type>(std::enable_if<std::integral_constant<bool, arrow::TypeTraits<arrow::Int64Type>::is_parameter_free>::value, arrow::MemoryPool*>::type)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow14NumericBuilderINS_9Int64TypeEEC2IS1_EENSt9enable_ifIXsrSt17integral_constantIbXsrNS_10TypeTraitsIT_EE17is_parameter_freeEE5valueEPNS_10MemoryPoolEE4typeE[_ZN5arrow14NumericBuilderINS_9Int64TypeEEC5IS1_EENSt9enable_ifIXsrSt17integral_constantIbXsrNS_10TypeTraitsIT_EE17is_parameter_freeEE5valueEPNS_10MemoryPoolEE4typeE]+0x61): undefined reference to `arrow::default_memory_pool()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::NumericBuilder<arrow::DoubleType>::NumericBuilder<arrow::DoubleType>(std::enable_if<std::integral_constant<bool, arrow::TypeTraits<arrow::DoubleType>::is_parameter_free>::value, arrow::MemoryPool*>::type)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow14NumericBuilderINS_10DoubleTypeEEC2IS1_EENSt9enable_ifIXsrSt17integral_constantIbXsrNS_10TypeTraitsIT_EE17is_parameter_freeEE5valueEPNS_10MemoryPoolEE4typeE[_ZN5arrow14NumericBuilderINS_10DoubleTypeEEC5IS1_EENSt9enable_ifIXsrSt17integral_constantIbXsrNS_10TypeTraitsIT_EE17is_parameter_freeEE5valueEPNS_10MemoryPoolEE4typeE]+0x61): undefined reference to `arrow::default_memory_pool()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::BaseListBuilder<arrow::ListType>::BaseListBuilder(arrow::MemoryPool*, std::shared_ptr<arrow::ArrayBuilder> const&)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow15BaseListBuilderINS_8ListTypeEEC2EPNS_10MemoryPoolERKSt10shared_ptrINS_12ArrayBuilderEE[_ZN5arrow15BaseListBuilderINS_8ListTypeEEC5EPNS_10MemoryPoolERKSt10shared_ptrINS_12ArrayBuilderEE]+0x59): undefined reference to `arrow::list(std::shared_ptr<arrow::DataType> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::Status arrow::Status::FromArgs<char const (&) [33]>(arrow::StatusCode, char const (&) [33])':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow6Status8FromArgsIJRA33_KcEEES0_NS_10StatusCodeEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow6Status8FromArgsIJRA33_KcEEES0_NS_10StatusCodeEDpOT_]+0x59): undefined reference to `arrow::Status::Status(arrow::StatusCode, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::Status arrow::Status::FromArgs<char const (&) [23]>(arrow::StatusCode, char const (&) [23])':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow6Status8FromArgsIJRA23_KcEEES0_NS_10StatusCodeEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow6Status8FromArgsIJRA23_KcEEES0_NS_10StatusCodeEDpOT_]+0x59): undefined reference to `arrow::Status::Status(arrow::StatusCode, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::BaseListBuilder<arrow::ListType>::BaseListBuilder(arrow::MemoryPool*, std::shared_ptr<arrow::ArrayBuilder> const&, std::shared_ptr<arrow::DataType> const&)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow15BaseListBuilderINS_8ListTypeEEC2EPNS_10MemoryPoolERKSt10shared_ptrINS_12ArrayBuilderEERKS5_INS_8DataTypeEE[_ZN5arrow15BaseListBuilderINS_8ListTypeEEC5EPNS_10MemoryPoolERKSt10shared_ptrINS_12ArrayBuilderEERKS5_INS_8DataTypeEE]+0xdd): undefined reference to `arrow::Field::WithType(std::shared_ptr<arrow::DataType> const&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::Status arrow::Status::FromArgs<char const (&) [26]>(arrow::StatusCode, char const (&) [26])':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow6Status8FromArgsIJRA26_KcEEES0_NS_10StatusCodeEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow6Status8FromArgsIJRA26_KcEEES0_NS_10StatusCodeEDpOT_]+0x59): undefined reference to `arrow::Status::Status(arrow::StatusCode, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > arrow::util::StringBuilder<char const (&) [33]>(char const (&) [33])':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA33_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA33_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_]+0x2c): undefined reference to `arrow::util::detail::StringStreamWrapper::StringStreamWrapper()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA33_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA33_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_]+0x65): undefined reference to `arrow::util::detail::StringStreamWrapper::str[abi:cxx11]()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA33_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA33_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_]+0x72): undefined reference to `arrow::util::detail::StringStreamWrapper::~StringStreamWrapper()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA33_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA33_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_]+0x97): undefined reference to `arrow::util::detail::StringStreamWrapper::~StringStreamWrapper()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > arrow::util::StringBuilder<char const (&) [23]>(char const (&) [23])':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA23_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA23_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_]+0x2c): undefined reference to `arrow::util::detail::StringStreamWrapper::StringStreamWrapper()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA23_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA23_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_]+0x65): undefined reference to `arrow::util::detail::StringStreamWrapper::str[abi:cxx11]()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA23_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA23_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_]+0x72): undefined reference to `arrow::util::detail::StringStreamWrapper::~StringStreamWrapper()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA23_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA23_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_]+0x97): undefined reference to `arrow::util::detail::StringStreamWrapper::~StringStreamWrapper()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > arrow::util::StringBuilder<char const (&) [26]>(char const (&) [26])':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA26_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA26_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_]+0x2c): undefined reference to `arrow::util::detail::StringStreamWrapper::StringStreamWrapper()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA26_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA26_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_]+0x65): undefined reference to `arrow::util::detail::StringStreamWrapper::str[abi:cxx11]()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA26_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA26_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_]+0x72): undefined reference to `arrow::util::detail::StringStreamWrapper::~StringStreamWrapper()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA26_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA26_KcEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_]+0x97): undefined reference to `arrow::util::detail::StringStreamWrapper::~StringStreamWrapper()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::Status arrow::Status::FromArgs<char const (&) [37], long, char const (&) [17], char const (&) [7], long const&>(arrow::StatusCode, char const (&) [37], long&&, char const (&) [17], char const (&) [7], long const&)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow6Status8FromArgsIJRA37_KclRA17_S2_RA7_S2_RKlEEES0_NS_10StatusCodeEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow6Status8FromArgsIJRA37_KclRA17_S2_RA7_S2_RKlEEES0_NS_10StatusCodeEDpOT_]+0xbe): undefined reference to `arrow::Status::Status(arrow::StatusCode, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > arrow::util::StringBuilder<char const (&) [37], long, char const (&) [17], char const (&) [7], long const&>(char const (&) [37], long&&, char const (&) [17], char const (&) [7], long const&)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA37_KclRA17_S2_RA7_S2_RKlEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA37_KclRA17_S2_RA7_S2_RKlEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_]+0x44): undefined reference to `arrow::util::detail::StringStreamWrapper::StringStreamWrapper()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA37_KclRA17_S2_RA7_S2_RKlEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA37_KclRA17_S2_RA7_S2_RKlEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_]+0xc5): undefined reference to `arrow::util::detail::StringStreamWrapper::str[abi:cxx11]()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA37_KclRA17_S2_RA7_S2_RKlEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA37_KclRA17_S2_RA7_S2_RKlEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_]+0xd2): undefined reference to `arrow::util::detail::StringStreamWrapper::~StringStreamWrapper()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA37_KclRA17_S2_RA7_S2_RKlEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA37_KclRA17_S2_RA7_S2_RKlEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_]+0xf7): undefined reference to `arrow::util::detail::StringStreamWrapper::~StringStreamWrapper()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<arrow::Schema>::construct<arrow::Schema, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Field>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Field> > >&>(arrow::Schema*, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Field>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Field> > >&)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIN5arrow6SchemaEE9constructIS2_JRSt6vectorISt10shared_ptrINS1_5FieldEESaIS8_EEEEEvPT_DpOT0_[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIN5arrow6SchemaEE9constructIS2_JRSt6vectorISt10shared_ptrINS1_5FieldEESaIS8_EEEEEvPT_DpOT0_]+0x70): undefined reference to `arrow::Schema::Schema(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Field>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Field> > > const&, std::shared_ptr<arrow::KeyValueMetadata const> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5arrow12BaseListTypeE[_ZTVN5arrow12BaseListTypeE]+0x20): undefined reference to `arrow::DataType::ComputeFingerprint[abi:cxx11]() const'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5arrow12BaseListTypeE[_ZTVN5arrow12BaseListTypeE]+0x28): undefined reference to `arrow::DataType::ComputeMetadataFingerprint[abi:cxx11]() const'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5arrow10NestedTypeE[_ZTVN5arrow10NestedTypeE]+0x20): undefined reference to `arrow::DataType::ComputeFingerprint[abi:cxx11]() const'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5arrow10NestedTypeE[_ZTVN5arrow10NestedTypeE]+0x28): undefined reference to `arrow::DataType::ComputeMetadataFingerprint[abi:cxx11]() const'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN5arrow14NumericBuilderINS_10DoubleTypeEEE[_ZTIN5arrow14NumericBuilderINS_10DoubleTypeEEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for arrow::ArrayBuilder'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN5arrow14NumericBuilderINS_9Int64TypeEEE[_ZTIN5arrow14NumericBuilderINS_9Int64TypeEEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for arrow::ArrayBuilder'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN5arrow15BaseListBuilderINS_8ListTypeEEE[_ZTIN5arrow15BaseListBuilderINS_8ListTypeEEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for arrow::ArrayBuilder'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTIN5arrow10NestedTypeE[_ZTIN5arrow10NestedTypeE]+0x18): undefined reference to `typeinfo for arrow::DataType'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::NumericBuilder<arrow::DoubleType>::Resize(long)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow14NumericBuilderINS_10DoubleTypeEE6ResizeEl[_ZN5arrow14NumericBuilderINS_10DoubleTypeEE6ResizeEl]+0x16a): undefined reference to `arrow::ArrayBuilder::Resize(long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::NumericBuilder<arrow::DoubleType>::AppendNulls(long)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow14NumericBuilderINS_10DoubleTypeEE11AppendNullsEl[_ZN5arrow14NumericBuilderINS_10DoubleTypeEE11AppendNullsEl]+0xd7): undefined reference to `arrow::ArrayBuilder::UnsafeSetNull(long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::NumericBuilder<arrow::DoubleType>::FinishInternal(std::shared_ptr<arrow::ArrayData>*)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow14NumericBuilderINS_10DoubleTypeEE14FinishInternalEPSt10shared_ptrINS_9ArrayDataEE[_ZN5arrow14NumericBuilderINS_10DoubleTypeEE14FinishInternalEPSt10shared_ptrINS_9ArrayDataEE]+0x266): undefined reference to `arrow::ArrayData::Make(std::shared_ptr<arrow::DataType> const&, long, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Buffer>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Buffer> > >&&, long, long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::NumericBuilder<arrow::Int64Type>::Resize(long)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow14NumericBuilderINS_9Int64TypeEE6ResizeEl[_ZN5arrow14NumericBuilderINS_9Int64TypeEE6ResizeEl]+0x16a): undefined reference to `arrow::ArrayBuilder::Resize(long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::NumericBuilder<arrow::Int64Type>::AppendNulls(long)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow14NumericBuilderINS_9Int64TypeEE11AppendNullsEl[_ZN5arrow14NumericBuilderINS_9Int64TypeEE11AppendNullsEl]+0xd8): undefined reference to `arrow::ArrayBuilder::UnsafeSetNull(long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::NumericBuilder<arrow::Int64Type>::FinishInternal(std::shared_ptr<arrow::ArrayData>*)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow14NumericBuilderINS_9Int64TypeEE14FinishInternalEPSt10shared_ptrINS_9ArrayDataEE[_ZN5arrow14NumericBuilderINS_9Int64TypeEE14FinishInternalEPSt10shared_ptrINS_9ArrayDataEE]+0x266): undefined reference to `arrow::ArrayData::Make(std::shared_ptr<arrow::DataType> const&, long, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Buffer>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Buffer> > >&&, long, long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::BaseListBuilder<arrow::ListType>::Resize(long)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow15BaseListBuilderINS_8ListTypeEE6ResizeEl[_ZN5arrow15BaseListBuilderINS_8ListTypeEE6ResizeEl]+0x19a): undefined reference to `arrow::ArrayBuilder::Resize(long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::BaseListBuilder<arrow::ListType>::Reset()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow15BaseListBuilderINS_8ListTypeEE5ResetEv[_ZN5arrow15BaseListBuilderINS_8ListTypeEE5ResetEv]+0x18): undefined reference to `arrow::ArrayBuilder::Reset()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::BaseListBuilder<arrow::ListType>::FinishInternal(std::shared_ptr<arrow::ArrayData>*)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow15BaseListBuilderINS_8ListTypeEE14FinishInternalEPSt10shared_ptrINS_9ArrayDataEE[_ZN5arrow15BaseListBuilderINS_8ListTypeEE14FinishInternalEPSt10shared_ptrINS_9ArrayDataEE]+0x568): undefined reference to `arrow::ArrayData::Make(std::shared_ptr<arrow::DataType> const&, long, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Buffer>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Buffer> > > const&, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<arrow::ArrayData>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<arrow::ArrayData> > > const&, long, long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::BaseListBuilder<arrow::ListType>::type() const':
test.cpp:(.text._ZNK5arrow15BaseListBuilderINS_8ListTypeEE4typeEv[_ZNK5arrow15BaseListBuilderINS_8ListTypeEE4typeEv]+0x70): undefined reference to `arrow::Field::WithType(std::shared_ptr<arrow::DataType> const&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `arrow::Status arrow::Status::FromArgs<char const (&) [47], long, char const (&) [6], long&>(arrow::StatusCode, char const (&) [47], long&&, char const (&) [6], long&)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow6Status8FromArgsIJRA47_KclRA6_S2_RlEEES0_NS_10StatusCodeEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow6Status8FromArgsIJRA47_KclRA6_S2_RlEEES0_NS_10StatusCodeEDpOT_]+0x9c): undefined reference to `arrow::Status::Status(arrow::StatusCode, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccvG1aV8.o: in function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > arrow::util::StringBuilder<char const (&) [47], long, char const (&) [6], long&>(char const (&) [47], long&&, char const (&) [6], long&)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA47_KclRA6_S2_RlEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA47_KclRA6_S2_RlEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_]+0x3e): undefined reference to `arrow::util::detail::StringStreamWrapper::StringStreamWrapper()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA47_KclRA6_S2_RlEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA47_KclRA6_S2_RlEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_]+0xad): undefined reference to `arrow::util::detail::StringStreamWrapper::str[abi:cxx11]()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA47_KclRA6_S2_RlEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA47_KclRA6_S2_RlEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_]+0xba): undefined reference to `arrow::util::detail::StringStreamWrapper::~StringStreamWrapper()'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text._ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA47_KclRA6_S2_RlEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_[_ZN5arrow4util13StringBuilderIJRA47_KclRA6_S2_RlEEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEDpOT_]+0xdf): undefined reference to `arrow::util::detail::StringStreamWrapper::~StringStreamWrapper()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

The code compiles correctly but fails to link. You need to supply the arrow library also to the `g++` command:

```
g++ -L<directoy-of-libarrow.so> -larrow test.cpp
```

e.g.

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -larrow test.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

First step: make a file named

> CMakeLists.txt

Second step: Paste the following text to the CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(test)
find_package(Arrow REQUIRED)
add_executable(test.o test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test.o PRIVATE arrow_shared)
```

Third step:

*cmake .*

*make*

Fourth step (execute the test project):

*./test.o*